# Kotlin StateFlow onStart unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to unit test my `ViewModel`. It has a `state` which is of the type `StateFlow`.
When I call my `useCase`, I set the value of the `state` to `Loading` in the `onStart` block as follows:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myUseCase: MyUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    // ...
    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<MyState> = MutableStateFlow(MyState.Loading)
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()
    
    init {
       loadData()    
    }

    fun loadData() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
          myUseCase().onStart {
             _state.value = MyState.Loading    
          }.collect { data ->
             // ...
             _state.value = MyState.Data(data)
          }
       }
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to test that the first emitted value from the flow is the `Loading` state but my test fails and says expected `Data` not `Loading`.

Here is my test class:

```kotlin
class MyViewModelTest {
   private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
   private lateinit var fakeUseCase: MyFakeUseCase

   @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        fakeUseCase = MyFakeUseCase()
        viewModel = MyViewModel(fakeUseCase)
    }

    @Test
    fun loadData_anyCriteria_stateIsLoadingOnStart() {
        runBlocking {
            // Act
            viewModel.loadData()
            val result = viewModel.state.first()

            // Assert
            Assertions.assertEquals(result, MyState.Loading)
        }
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
Expected :Data(bla bla bla)

Actual   :com.example....MyState$Loading@7b8233cd
```

How can I test the first value emitted from a `StateFlow`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I found that adding in a delay in your `runBlocking` or `runTest` before the assertion works.